# Counting numbers from a .txt file

Tags: c, file-io

I am attempting to write a function which outputs the count of numbers in the file grade_data.txt. The issue I'm having is getting it to read in the file properly to count each number every time a number is written to a dummy variable. dgrade_data.txt contains integer values such as:
89
73
95
48
66
90
83
79

I tried using:

`int temp;
while (fscanf(fpin, "%d", temp) != EOF) count++;`

however, this gave me the same issue as the original code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fpin,;
    fpin = fopen("grade_data.txt", "r");
    if(fpin = NULL) {
        printf("FILE DOES NOT EXIST");
        exit(0);
    }

    printf("Number of students:\t%d", fcount());
    fclose(fpin);
}

int fcount(void){
    int count;
    char c;
    FILE *fpin;
    fpin = fopen("grade_data.txt", "r");

    if (fpin = NULL) {
        printf("FILE DOES NOT EXIST");
        exit(0);
    }
    // Extract characters from file and store in character c 
    for (c = getc(fpin); c != EOF; c = getc(fp)) 
        if (c != '\n' && c ) 
        // Increment count if this character is newline 
        count = count + 1

    fclose(fpin);
    return count;
}
```

I expected the output to be 7 for the data above, however, I continually get an error which tells me the program has stopped working

Comment: Why are you opening the file two times, one in `main` and one in `fcount`? Also, why does your comment say "*Increment count if this character is newline*" when the code does the opposite?

Comment: @user3121023 No, `while(fscanf(...) != EOF)` is almost always a bad idea.  Much better would be `while(fscanf(...) == 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are opening the file twice, both in main() and in the function. Then, the function is placed under main() instead of above it, so I suppose the error you are getting is that the function has not been declared. Apart from that, you have not declared fp, so I assume you meant fpin. Then, why are you using getc() twice in the for loop? This is causing the first character read to be discarded. A do-while loop would suffice:

```
do
{
    c = getc(fpin);
    if (c != '\n' && c) count++;
    // Increment count if this character is newline <--You are doing the exact opposite
}while(c!=EOF)
```

This loop is reading individual characters, so I doubt this is what you want it to do.
If you use this instead, the program should run fine:

```
int temp;
while (fscanf(fpin, "%d", &temp) != EOF) count++;
```

Comment: Just make sure the input doesn't contain any non-numbers!  If it does (if it contains, say, the character `'a'` anywhere) the `fscanf` loop will run forever...